# What does "get" really mean in "I get you want to help"?

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context

> I get you want to help.

Does *get* in this context mean "know"? Or "understand"?

Comment: I think this ought to be migrated to [ell.se], but that's just my opinion. And yes, the word "get" in this context means "know" or "understand". Another good substitution might be "realize": _I realize you want to help._

Comment: Some people tend to use 'get' as a substitute for 'understand' or 'gather'. 'Do you get me?', some will say after explaining something a bit complicated. It is an unsophisticated slang use and not something recommended for an important interview!

Comment: In this context, it means _grok_.

Comment: And I've never heard it used with a main clause (I get you want to help) rather than a noun phrase (Ah, I get Bob now) or a what-clause (I get what you mean). 'Understand' accepts all three (the first a reduced that-clause).

Comment: @Edwin, it is quite common with a subordinate clause (not a main clause). “Yes, I get that you want me to help you, but I can’t help you unless you tell me how!”, for example, is perfectly common, though perhaps more AmE than BrE.

Comment: @Janus You're right – there are a lot of hits on Google for 'I get you want' (but none on Google Ngram). I'm tempted to become prescriptivist on this one.

Answer (score 2):

When you "get it", you understand something, therefore, in this context:

> I get = I understand

Comment: It can be risky arguing for parallels even using apparently closely related structures, mirabelle, especially where idioms are involved: 'When you "beat it", you hurriedly leave somewhere, therefore _I beat = I hurriedly leave_.' [F] The fact that 'beat it' is widely used and understood doesn't guarantee that 'beat' can be used similarly without the 'it'.

Comment: certainly - context is king.

Comment: So the 'therefore' is not necessarily (I'd say _not_) accurate here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth updated. You're picky ;-)

Comment: English _is_ finicky. If you've just spent hours finalising the best scheme of work ever, you don't necessarily want to be labelled a schemer.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, "get" means to understand something said (or hinted) by someone else.

Normally, "get" means to receive something from another person: "I got your letter" means "I received the letter that *you gave me*.

Therefore, the sentence "I get you want to help" means "I received the information that *you told (or implied to) me*, which is that you want to help."